# Heroku - DO CRON jobs keep working when the app is "asleep"?

Tags: node.js, heroku, cron

I have programmed my app to trigger some `CRON Jobs` everyday at 9 a.m, and it works on `localhost`.

My app is running on sandbox mode, with only one dyno, so I know it falls asleep after 1 hour of non activity.

What happens exactly internally when the app falls asleep ? Is it the reason why my Cron Jobs don't work ? It would be rather cumbersome to verify...

I'm using node.js + heroku + node-cron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the time comes for the app to sleep [Heroku sends the SIGTERM signal](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-sleeping) to the process which will most likely kill the process in your case, preventing the cron jobs from running. It is possible to catch and ignore the SIGTERM signal but Heroku will in that case probably just forcibly shut down your process using the SIGKILL signal, like it does [when restarting dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#shutdown).

One possible workaround is to use the [New Relic addon](https://addons.heroku.com/newrelic) to [regularly ping/monitor a URL](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts/alert-policies/downtime-alerts/downtime-alert-settings#configure) in your app, preventing it from sleeping. However, using this approach together with node-cron could be problematic since Heroku restarts all dynos at least once a day. If the restart occurs when the cron job would trigger it might not trigger the cron job that day.

Another possibility is to instead of using node-cron use the [Heroku Scheduler addon](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler) to run your periodic tasks.